# Python SourceDefender ImportError

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I have been trying to get sourcedefender (https://pypi.org/project/sourcedefender/) to work on a laptop running PiDesktop and and windows 7 machine both with the same issue. PiDesktop is running python 3.7 and the windows machine is running Python 3.8.

Both come back with

> ImportError: cannot import name 'loader' from 'sourcedefender'

```
D:\Python Stuff>sourcedefender encrypt test_stuff.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adam.hedley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\sourcedefender-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('sourcedefender==6.0.21', 'console_scripts', 'sourcedefender')()
  File "C:\Users\adam.hedley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "C:\Users\adam.hedley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2862, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "C:\Users\adam.hedley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2462, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "C:\Users\adam.hedley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2468, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\adam.hedley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sourcedefender-6.0.21-py3.8.egg\sourcedefender\__init__.py", lin
e 3, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'loader' from 'sourcedefender' (C:\Users\adam.hedley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sourcede
fender-6.0.21-py3.8.egg\sourcedefender\__init__.py)
```

Exactly the same result if I also try `sourcedefender encrypt --ttl=1d test_stuff.py`
I am hoping someone may have a simple solution.